# How do I take a video version of screenshot on iPod Touch 4th Gen?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, screen-capture

I want to create videos of myself doing app demos on my iPod, how do I create a video version of screen shot?

Answer (score 1):

You could try Reflector (reflector.com) which is an app that runs on your Mac and grabs sound & video from your ios device over airplay. There's also AirServer but I found that wasn't nearly as responsive and it didn't have video recording ability. Reflector was called Reflection until recently.